# convenience method for combine publishers

Tags: ios, swift, monads, combine

I find myself wanting the same functionality in Combine quite often, so I wanted to make a convenience method like so...

```
public extension Published.Publisher {
    func sinkChanges(receiveValue: @escaping (Self.Output) -> Void) -> AnyCancellable {
        self.dropFirst()
            .removeDuplicates()
            .sink(receiveValue: closure)
    }
}
```

However I'm pretty new to the syntax and I get the error

`Referencing instance method 'removeDuplicates()' on 'Publisher' requires that 'Publishers.Drop<Published<Value>.Publisher>.Output' (aka 'Value') conform to 'Equatable'`

I understand why and what I have to do, just no idea syntactically where it goes...

My best guess so far was
`public extension Published.Publisher where Output: Equatable {`
but it didn't like that... what should I be searching for?

Comment: "but it didn't like that..." really? It worked for me though. What version of Xcode are you using? And what was the error message that you got?

Comment: Protocol ***Conditional Conformance*** is a pretty powerful pattern in Swift. Give it a chance .

Comment: So strange, I'm not sure what happened when I tried it, maybe I put `Value: Equatable` anyway, thanks for confirming! No idea what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** Your best guess is correct.

---

As you might've noticed (and according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/removeduplicates())), the method `removeDuplicates()` is only available, when `Output` conforms to `Equatable`. If you want to use this method in your extension, you must guarantee that. And to do that, you can add a constraint exactly as you described:

```swift
import Combine

public extension Published.Publisher where Output: Equatable {
  func sinkChanges(receiveValue: @escaping (Output) -> Void) -> AnyCancellable {
    dropFirst().removeDuplicates().sink(receiveValue: receiveValue)
  }
}
```

There's nothing wrong with extension constraints, it's a language feature. [Here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/specialized-extensions-using-generic-type-constraints/)'s one post about it.

Comment: Oh that's crazy.... I wonder why I couldn't get it to work.. Maybe I tried `Value: Equatable` thanks!